# Extension to Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem (required property of a convergent subsequence)

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

According to Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem, it says that any bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a convergent subsequence.

Assume that $\{\mathbf{x}_\nu\}$ is a given bounded sequence and $\{\nu_k\}$ is the index set of a convergent subsequence. Can we assume that $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\nu_k-\nu_{k-1}<\infty$? (i.e. subsequent iterates are in finite distance of each other.)

If yes, why do you claim that?

If not, is there any requirement on the sequence $\{\mathbf{x}_\nu\}$ by which, existence of such a convergent subsequence can be guaranteed?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You can consider $\{x_v\}_{v=1}^{\infty}=\{0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...\}$.  The only possible values a subsequence can converge to are $0$ or $1$, but either way, we need to skip a progressively large number of indices to converge there.

Comment: @Michael yes , you're right. So how can I guarantee that property? is there any assumption I can make on the whole sequence to have that property?

Comment: Hmm...if we want to enforce that property...right now I find it hard to give a meaningful characteristic for the sequence to have that is not just a trivial restatement of the desired property itself.

Comment: @Michael OK, yes. However thanks for the answer. Anyway if you know a good source that I might be able study that and find something, let me know. Thanks again

Comment: For intuition:  Consider an iid sequence of random variables $\{X_1, X_2, X_3, ...\}$, each uniform over $[0,1]$.  I believe I can show that, with probability 1, there does _not_ exist a convergent subsequence that satisfies your property.  So, your property is rare, at least if the sequence is sufficiently "random."  I might write that up as an answer if I have time.

Comment: wow that seems dissapointing for me. However my sequnce is generated by a convex combination of a new point and its previous point, i.e. $x^{\nu+1}=(1-\gamma)x^{\nu}+\gamma \hat{x}$

Comment: Well it would depend on how $\hat{x}$ relates to the previous values.

Comment: the new point $\hat{x}$ doesn't have a clear relation with iterates, and it's kind of best response of a subproblems, so we can treat it as an independent coming data.

Comment: the clear relaton is $\hat{x}=argmin_x ~f(x;x^\nu)$, where $f(x;x^\nu)$ is a function of $x$ depending on $x^\nu$.

Comment: @Michael sorry I forgot to mention that convex combination is variying and  $\lim_{\nu\rightarrow \infty}~\gamma^\nu=0$ and $\{(\gamma^\nu)^2\}_\nu$ is summable and $\{(\gamma^\nu)\}_\nu$ unsummable (this sequnce can be generated by $\gamma^{\nu+1}=\gamma^{\nu}(1-\epsilon \gamma^{\nu})$). It's all I have about the sequence. :)

Comment: @Michael smart comment, but as you see in my previous comment, I mentioned that $\gamma^\nu$ is not summable :( Actually it's a update rule for a class of algorithms and by having unsummable $\gamma^\nu$, it enables the iterates to reach all possible points (which might be a solution) in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Well I deleted my comment but it makes sense to put it back:  Suppose we change the notation to $$x[k+1]=(1-\gamma[k])x[k] + \gamma[k]r[k]$$ Then we get $x[k+1]-x[k]=\gamma[k](r[k]-x[k])$ and summing over $k \in \{0, ..., n-1\}$ gives $x[n]-x[0] = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\gamma[k](r[k]-x[k])$.  If $\gamma[k]$ _were_ summable and if $r[k]-x[k]$ were in a bounded region, then indeed $x[n]$ would converge.  Since $\gamma[k]$ is _not_ summable, we might need $r[k]-x[k]$ to get progressively smaller for $x[k]$ to converge.

Comment: Martingale convergence theorems might be useful if the random structure of $r[k]$ can be described nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Four miscellaneous observations:

---

1) Consider $\{x_k\}=\{0, 1, 1, 0,0, 0, 1,1,1, 1, 0,0,0,0, 0,  …\}$.  The only values a convergent subsequence could converge to are 0 or 1, but either way we would need to skip a progressively growing number of indices.

---

2) Let $\{X_1, X_2, X_3, …\}$ be a sequence of iid random variables with a continuous CDF function $F_X(x) = P[X\leq x]$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

#### Claim:

With probability 1, $\{X_1, X_2, X_3, …\}$ does *not* contain a convergent subsequence $X_{n[k]}$ that satisfies $\limsup_{k \rightarrow\infty} (n[k+1]-n[k]) < \infty$.

#### Proof:

For any rational numbers $a,b$ such that $a<b$, the law of large numbers tells us that: 
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n1\{X_i \in [a,b]\} = F_X(b)-F_X(a) \quad (w.p.1) $$
where $1\{X_i \in [a,b]\}$ is an indicator function that is 1 if $X_i \in [a,b]$, and $0$ else. There are only a countably infinite number of rational intervals   $[a,b]$. Hence, with probability 1, the above holds for *all* rational intervals.

Now suppose $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ contains a convergent subsequence of the desired form. So there is a real number $c \in \mathbb{R}$, an integer  $M>0$, and a subsequence $n[k]$ such that $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} X_{n[k]} = c$ and $\limsup_{k\rightarrow\infty} (n[k+1]-n[k]) \leq M$.  The latter implies that $n[k+1]-n[k]\leq M$ for all sufficiently large $k$ (since $n[k+1]-n[k]$ is integer-valued).  Fix $\delta>0$ such that 
$$ F_X(c+\delta) - F_X(c-\delta) \leq 1/(2M)$$
This is possible because the $F_X$ function is continuous.  Fix rational numbers $a,b$ such that $a<c<b$ and 
$$ c-\delta \leq a < c < b \leq c + \delta $$
Since $F_X$ is nondecreasing, we get: 
 $$ F_X(b) - F_X(a) \leq F_X(c+\delta)-F_X(c-\delta) \leq 1/(2M) < 1/M \quad (*)$$
The subsequence $\{X_{n[k]}\}$ converges to $c$ and so it is in the interval $[a,b]$ for all sufficiently large $k$. Hence, eventually the 
sequence $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ will fall into the interval $[a,b]$ at least once every $M$ steps, and so:
$$ \liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n 1\{X_i \in [a,b]\} \geq 1/M > F_X(b)-F_X(a)$$
where the final inequality holds by (*). 
Thus: 
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n 1\{X_i \in [a,b]\} \neq F_X(b)-F_X(a) $$
Hence, $[a,b]$ is a rational interval over which the law of large numbers result does not work.  This occurs with probability 0. $\Box$

---

3) Take the iteration: 
$$ x[k+1]=(1-\gamma[k])x[k] + \gamma[k]r[k] $$
where $x[0]$ is a given real number, $\gamma[k]$ is a given square-summable sequence, and $r[k]$ is random.

Suppose that $E[(x[k]-r[k])^2] \leq B$ for all $k$, for some constant $B$. Suppose that 
$$E[r[k]|x[0],x[1],...,x[k]]=x[k]$$ 
Then $x[k]$ is a martingale.  Further, we have for all $k$: 
$$ x[k+1]-x[k] = \gamma[k](r[k]-x[k]) $$
Summing over $k\in\{0, ..., n-1\}$ gives: 
$$ x[n] - x[0] = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \gamma[k](r[k]-x[k]) $$
Hence: 
$$ E[(x[n]-x[0])^2] = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\gamma[k]^2E[(r[k]-x[k])^2] \leq B\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\gamma[k]^2 $$
where we have used the fact that $E[(r[k]-x[k])(r[i]-x[i])]=0$ for $i\neq k$. 
So $\sup_n E[x[n]^2]$ is bounded.  By the $L^2$-bounded martingale convergence theorem, we know $x[n]$ converges with probability 1.

---

4) Consider $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ iid uniform over $[0,1]$.

#### Claim:

With prob 1, we can find a convergent subsequence $\{X_{n[k]}\}$ that converges to $0.5$ and that satisfies $n[k+1]-n[k] \leq k^{1/2}$ for all sufficiently large $k$.

Proof: 
Define the subsequence as follows: Define $n[1]=1$. For $k\in\{2, 3, 4, ...\}$, greedily select $n[k]$ as the first integer $n>n[k-1]$ for which:
$$X_n \in \left[.5-\frac{1}{2k^{1/4}}, .5+\frac{1}{2k^{1/4}}\right]$$ 
By construction, the $\{X_{n[k]}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ subsequence will converge to $0.5$.  We just need to show the distances between $n[k]$ grow sublinearly.  Notice that at stage $k$, the probability of a sample $X_n$ falling in the above interval is $1/k^{1/4}$.

Define $Wait[k] = n[k+1]-n[k]$. Fix $k \in \{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$. For simplicity, treat $k^{1/2}$ as an integer. Then:
$$P[Wait[k] > k^{1/2}] = (1-1/k^{1/4})^{k^{1/2}} = \left((1-1/k^{1/4})^{k^{1/4}}\right)^{k^{1/4}} \approx (1/e)^{k^{1/4}} $$
This decays rapidly.  Notice that: 
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} P[Wait[k]>k^{1/2}] < \infty$$ 
It follows by Borel-Cantelli that, with prob 1, at most a finite number of the events $\{Wait[k]>k^{1/2}\}$ occur. In particular, $Wait[k] \leq k^{1/2}$ for all sufficiently large $k$. $\Box$

Comment: Thanks a lot for this descriptive answer. Now it's so much clearer to me. I liked how you proved the second observation. In the third observation, actually assumption $E[(r[k]-x[k])(r[i]-x[i])]=0$ doesn't hold and that is the main problem I have for proving convergence of the sequence. If I could somewhow show that $r[k]-x[k]$ decays with rate of at least $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{\gamma[k]})$, then we could remove that assumption and convergence could be proved. For proving this fact, one needs to deal with the optimization problem that we solve for calculating $r[k]$ which it's quite tough to show.

Comment: Another proof of observation 2 in a more general scenario: Suppose $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is iid and there are two real numbers $x,y$ with $x<y$ such that $$ P[X_n \leq x]>0, P[X_n\geq y]>0$$ Then with prob 1 there is no convergent subsequence with the desired property.  This is because, with prob 1, there are arbitrarily large run lengths of the event $\{X_n\leq x\}$, and also arbitrarily large run lengths of the event $\{X_n\geq y\}$. Under these conditions, any convergent subsequence must have arbitrarily large run lengths of skipped indices.

Comment: Great thanks for the proof, but as you know, I need to use, somehow, some property of my problem in order to show the existence of such a subsequence. So your second observation is eye-opening but I think that its claim about the fact that such a sequence is rare is due to our general assumption on the sequence of variates and hopefully it might not apply to my case.

Comment: I know.  I just found the general Bolzano-Wierstrass question interesting and wanted to give an alternative proof.  If you can formulate a more precise question for your specific problem, you might want to do that, perhaps linking to this question for background.  It was not clear to me what your $\hat{x}$ really is, or what the $f$ function is, so more details on that would likely be needed.  You might also want to consider relaxed versions of your subsequence condition, like $n[k+1]-n[k]$ grows at most linearly (rather than being bounded).

Comment: The intuition is this:  Even if $\{X_i\}$ are iid, I think you can still find convergent subsequences (with prob 1) with $n[k+1]-n[k]$ that grows at most linearly, even though this is impossible when we require $n[k+1]-n[k]$ to be bounded.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am trying to digest your proof and extend it for proving your suggestion. I might be able to prove some results if I can show that $\nu_k-\nu_{k-1}$ grows (strictly) sublinear with $k$.

Comment: Wow it's not that easy at all. I was wondeing if you can give me some hint about how to prove existence (almost surely) such a subsequence that $\nu_{k}-\nu_{k-1}$ grows as $k^t,\quad t\in[0,1)$?

Comment: @Amir : I added a proof of that for $n[k+1]-n[k]\leq O(k^{1/2})$ and for iid uniform variables.

Comment: Thank you very much Dr. Neely. This will help me a lot.

Comment: I will send you my results later as I complete them, in case you are curious why I needed this lemma. :) Thanks

Comment: One more question. Can we remove independence assumption on the random variables? I mean, we only assume $X1,X_2,\ldots$ are identically distributed and not indipendently?

Comment: In the last proof, it doesn't seem to need any independence between the variables, right? but I am not sure about it :)

Comment: @Amir : Feel free to send me that, I'd be interested to see the context.   For independence, I used that assumption for $P[Wait[k]>k^{1/2}] = (1-1/k^{1/4})^{k^{1/2}}$ (which multiplies $k^{1/2}$ probabilities associated with independent events). Otherwise we could generate $A$ and $B$ as iid uniform random variables in $[0,1]$ (they are different with prob 1) and have the sequence $\{A, B, B, A, A, A, B, B, B, B, A, A, A, A, A...\}$, with run lengths that grow arbitrarily large.   However, back to the iid case, I believe you can improve on the upper bound $k^{1/2}$ to make this smaller.

Comment: yes yes, I recognized it shortly. Excuse my negligence. I was wondering if you have any intuition for proving the same results for $\textit{non}$ independent i.d random variables? I think it should be fine, because correlation between the iterates must help convergence and assuming independence between iterates must be the worst case, right?

Comment: Sorry I am asking too many questions :) However as you know and as I mentioned before, every iterate is a convex combination of previous iteration and best response of a subproblem $\hat{x}[\nu]$, i.e. ($x[\nu+1]=(1-\gamma[\nu])x[\nu]+\gamma[\nu]\hat{x}[\nu]$). As you see, there is correlation between iterates. I want to assume that $\hat{x}^\nu$ is a iid random variable and prove the same results as you did for that series of iid random variables.

Comment: However still $\hat{x}[\nu]$ is not independent form previous point, but I am searching for some concrete justification that "assuming $\hat{x}[\nu]$ to be a iid RV is the worst case scenario in having nice convergence properties".